# IntelliJ Idea Glassfish Error during EAR artifact deployment A valid ejb jar required

Tags: deployment, intellij-idea, ejb, glassfish-3, ear

I am getting this error during EJB.ear artifact deployment to Glassfish 3.1.2 Application Server from within IntelliJ Idea 14.0.3:

```
Connected to server
[2015-09-03 06:32:26,411] Artifact MyEar:ear: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2015-09-03 06:32:26,412] Artifact MyEar:ear: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [MyEar] : Invalid ejb jar [MyEjb-3.2.0.jar]: it contains zero ejb. 
Note: 
1. A valid ejb jar requires at least one session, entity (1.x/2.x style), or message-driven bean. 
2. EJB3+ entity beans (@Entity) are POJOs and please package them as library jar. 
3. If the jar file contains valid EJBs which are annotated with EJB component level annotations (@Stateless, @Stateful, @MessageDriven, @Singleton), please check server.log to see whether the annotations were processed properly.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

The EJB.ear, and the other war files are all ok and can be deployed successfully externally via Glassfish Admin console. 
One thing I note is that I have to check the compatibility check-box while deployment from Glassfish Admin console.

See attached screenshot below and then it installs successfully.
**How to achieve this same compatibility check for EAR deployment from within IntelliJ Idea ?**

[image]